# How do I always download the latest version of phpmyadmin with python?

Tags: python-3.x, hyperlink, download, phpmyadmin, version

I always want to automatically download the latest version of phpmyadmin using a python script. https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/ The problem is that if I insert the link of the latest version in my Script (https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/5.0.1/phpMyAdmin-5.0. 1-all-languages.zip) and eventually version 5.0.2 comes out, the script still downloads version 5.0.1.

Does anyone have an idea how to always download the latest version using the same link?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.phpmyadmin.net/about-website/

https://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/version.txt contains all you need to build a script.

For automatically checking version information, we have several file formats available as well:

https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/list.txt - list of all current downloads for latest version

https://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/version.txt - version, date and download URL for latest version

https://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/version.js - embeddable javascript code with version and release date information

https://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/version.json - JSON with version and release date information

Comment: https://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/list.txt says "Page not found".

Comment: I updated the links, thank you !
I had forgot to use full links, the folders are not the same.